# How to convert between Profit Margin % and Markup %

Tags: c#, margin, formula, markup

I am writing a code where I need to convert between the profit margin % to the markup %

For example if I type 50% Profit Margin then the Markup % should be 100%. If I type 75% profit Margin then the markup % will = 300%.

I found this link that gives the formulas
http://larig.wordpress.com/2010/07/06/convert-between-margin-and-mark-up/

```
|margin| = 1 - 1 / (1 + |markup|)
|markup| = 1 / (1 - |margin|) - 1
```

when I tried to apply the formula I do not get the desired results. (This formula did not make since and it is not calculating correctly.)

Here is what I have done using C#

```
InputMarkup.Text = Math.Abs((1 / (1 - Math.Abs(margin) - 1))).ToString();
```

I also tried this

```
InputMarkup.Text = Math.Abs((1 / (1 - Math.Abs(margin))) - 1).ToString()
```

Comment: Is your question related with programming? Which language are you using? There is a sample of your code?

Comment: Check the parenthesis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. 
The formula was incorrect

this is the correct formula

[Converting Between Markup vs Margin](http://www.double-entry-bookkeeping.com/gross-margin/markup-vs-margin/)

> In the event that you know either the markup or the margin and need to know the other, then the following formulas will help you
>   calculate. Markup = Margin / (1 – Margin)
>
> So for example if the margin is 33.33% or 0.3333 them the markup is
>   given by Markup = 0.3333 / 1 – 0.3333 = 0.3333 / 0.6667 = 0.50 or 50%
>   and, Margin = Markup / (1 + Markup)
>
> So for example if the markup is 50% or 0.5 then the margin is given by
>   Margin = 0.5 / (1 + 0.5) = 0.5 / 1.5 = 0.3333 or 33.33%

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple. In your terminology, markup = profit / (1 - profit). Check with your examples: 0.50 / (1 - 0.50) = 1.00 is correct, 0.75 / (1 - 0.75) = 3.00 is also correct.

Answer (score 0):

They must be in fraction format...
Example mark up (25%) and margin(20%)
Divide by 100. Mark up (1/4) and margin (1/5).
From mark up to margin (1+4---> 5 ) then the upper fraction ,in this case, 1 is in the same position---> 1/5